# Access to api response data

Tags: reactjs

My code pass in a search term and the promise api call returns one record and the data format is as below:

` json api data

```
 0:
   {
    id:"aff3b4fa-bdc0-47d1-947f-0163ff5bea06"
    keyword: somekeyword
    URL:"mypage.html"
   }
```

I need to retrieve the URL value, so I try to get URL by using response.data[0].URL. But I receive the error "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): response.data[0] is undefined". How do I get the URL value? Thanks.

` autocomplete.js

```
export class Autocomplete extends Component {
  state = {
    activeSuggestion: 0,
    filteredSuggestions: [],
    showSuggestions: false,
    userInput: "",
    suggestions: [],
    results: [],
    URL: "",
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.GetPrograms();
    const { userInput } = this.state;
    //this.runSearch();
  }
  GetPrograms = () => {
    axios
      .get("https://mydomain/GetPrograms/")
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ suggestions: response.data });
      });
  };

  runSearch = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      "https://mydomain/api/get",
      {
        params: {
          searchTerm: this.state.userInput,
        },
      }
    );

    let results = response.data;
    console.log("response", results);
    this.setState({ results: results, URL: response.data[0].URL });
    window.location.href =
      "https://mydomain/" + this.state.URL;
  };
  
  onChange = (e) => {
    const { suggestions } = this.state; //this.props;
    const userInput = e.currentTarget.value;

    const filteredSuggestions = suggestions.filter(
      (suggestion) =>
        suggestion.toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput.toLowerCase()) > -1
    );

    this.setState({
      activeSuggestion: 0,
      filteredSuggestions,
      showSuggestions: true,
      userInput: e.currentTarget.value,
    });
  };

  onClick = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      activeSuggestion: 0,
      filteredSuggestions: [],
      showSuggestions: false,
      userInput: e.currentTarget.innerText,
    });

    this.onSearch();
    console.log(
      "child component clicked and value=" + e.currentTarget.innerText
    );
  };

  onKeyDown = (e) => {
    const { activeSuggestion, filteredSuggestions } = this.state;

    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      this.setState({
        activeSuggestion: 0,
        showSuggestions: false,
        userInput: filteredSuggestions[activeSuggestion],
      });
    } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
      if (activeSuggestion === 0) {
        return;
      }

      this.setState({ activeSuggestion: activeSuggestion - 1 });
    } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
      if (activeSuggestion - 1 === filteredSuggestions.length) {
        return;
      }

      this.setState({ activeSuggestion: activeSuggestion + 1 });
    }
    //this.setState({ searchTerm: e.currentTarget.value });
    console.log("userinput:" + this.state.userInput);
  };

  render() {
    const {
      onChange,
      onClick,
      onKeyDown,
      onKeyPress,
      state: {
        activeSuggestion,
        filteredSuggestions,
        showSuggestions,
        userInput,
      },
    } = this;
    let suggestionsListComponent;
    if (showSuggestions && userInput) {
      if (filteredSuggestions.length) {
        suggestionsListComponent = (
          <ul class="suggestions">
            {filteredSuggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
              let className;

              if (index === activeSuggestion) {
                className = "";
              }

              return (
                <li key={suggestion} onClick={onClick}>
                  {suggestion}
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        );
      } else {
        suggestionsListComponent = (
          <div class="no-suggestions">
            <em>No suggestions</em>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <input
          id="search-box"
          placeholder="Search..."
          type="search"
          onChange={onChange}
          onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
          value={userInput}
        />
        {suggestionsListComponent}

      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Autocomplete;

`
```

Comment: Can you console.log the response? Sounds like data may be nested deeper inside the reponse

Comment: You should post your code so we can evaluate what's wrong and help you... Without this it's kinda hard to guide you

Comment: probably you got an empty array as response, so [0] element of that array is undefined, so you can't access `.URL` property of it

Comment: @Sergey is correct, the response has 0 record.

Answer (score 0):

The api call returns 0 record that causes the error.